# Is there a way to inject a CSS on a specific website using nsIStyleSheetService?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, stylesheet

I am trying to inject a stylesheet file using `nsIStyleSheetService`.

When I do that it injects the style on all pages, but I want to target just some websites.

Is it possible?

My code:

```
LoadStyleSheet = function(source) {
     var sss = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
     var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
     var uri = ios.newURI("chrome://addon/content/css/" + source, null, null);

     if(!sss.sheetRegistered(uri, sss.AGENT_SHEET))
         sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.AGENT_SHEET);
};
```

and

```
if (/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+google.*/i.test(window.location.href))
{
    LoadStyleSheet("config.css"); // register the style on all pages
    // while my target is just Google
}
```

Comment: Maybe try taking a look at [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) because I think what you're trying to do is pretty similar to what it does.

Comment: I'm not sure why the regex test seems not to be working though. Try sending `window.location.href` to the console maybe.

Comment: @MatrixFrog, the regex test does work. But when it fires once all websites are affected...

Comment: Interesting. Not sure why that would be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you likely want to specify `USER_SHEET` instead of `AGENT_SHEET`.  Secondly, you have to specify what is applied in your stylesheet [like this code](http://rtse.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rtse/trunk/chrome/content/styles.css?revision=586&view=markup).  More information [can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document).